# How to Auto close or hide this asp.net home page window when opened the project in visual studio programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility

How to close or hide this page? I created a custom project template which outputs the asp.net mvc project or aspnet core template and opens this page as tabbed document. How to close this programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be done using the development tool environment object

```
public void RunFinished()
        {
           Solution2 soln = (Solution2)dte.Solution;
//Close the .Net project overview home page from the output project to be created
            foreach (Window documentWindow in dte.Windows)
            {
                //close all Document type of windows from the output project
                if (documentWindow.Kind == "Document")
                {
                    documentWindow.Close();
                }
            }
}
```